# Is it safe to install ubuntu in legacy mode?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, uefi

I think i installed windows with UEFI but either way i want windows gone. I am currently using ubuntu 14.04 LTS from a live usb. When I try to boot in UEFI mode I get a black screen and when I hit "try ubuntu" it dosent do anything,but in legacy mode it works fine. is it safe to install ubuntu in legacy mode (I dont plan on dual booting, i want to fully replace windows with ubuntu,meaning ubuntu wiping the drive and installing itself in windows place) btw I have windows 8.1 if that helps. i tried to install and it says no other operating systems found.

Does it even matter what mode I do it in? it will just wipe the drive and install ubuntu right? I have 4 partitions all windows so should i get rid of the recovery partitons before i install ubuntu or should i just leave them? sorry if this is confusing im a complete ubuntu noob and i just want some answers please. Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Define "safe"... I mean the computer isn't going to melt into a puddle on the floor or blow up and kill you or anything.

Comment: Safe as in will it cause any harm to the computer, like will it not boot to windows or ubuntu? will it brick the computer? im broke so if i screw something up im f*****

Comment: You said you wanted to blow windows away anyway and you can't brick a computer by installing an OS...

Answer (score 1):

There are advantages to EFI mode (such as faster boot times and better access to firmware settings from the OS), but for a single-boot installation, either *should* work fine, and neither *should* pose any danger of physical damage to the computer. Note the *shoulds,* though. There is at least one known bug that can cause EFIs to brick themselves if too much data is written to the NVRAM. This particular problem can occur in EFI mode but not in BIOS mode, though, so the greater risk actually lies in EFI mode. (This problem was responsible for the infamous Samsung bricking problem that caused a big frenzy about a year ago.) The Linux kernel now includes checks to avoid this problem while Linux is booted. It's conceivable that there are other risks out there that might affect either mode, but I know of no specific threat at the moment, aside from the bricking issue I just noted.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really matter which you install it in. If you need to install Ubuntu in Legacy Mode, go right ahead. I would recommend though that you try to delete all partitions before running the installer.

Comment: UEFI allows for larger HDD and a gpt partition table, so there is an advantage. It's possible you may have just needed to tweak the grub entry to boot Ubuntu and get past the black screen. You can always try removing 'quiet splash' and adding 'nomodeset' to see if that works.

Comment: Yeah, but remember that Legacy Mode is his only choice. There are some small disadvantages, many of which don't affect him, but it's the only way.

Comment: I now have it installed and everything is fine except one thing... everytime i reboot ubuntu seems to forget my brightness settings, automatically putting it back to the default (maximum) brightness. is this because of legacy or is this someting else? thanks for your time again :)

Comment: I doubt it is because of Legacy Mode because I am on a UEFI system right now and the same thing happens to me. This could be a coincidence but Ubuntu has a hardware compatibility problem with my laptop that makes it so I couldn't adjust the brightness. I fixed it by modifying a GRUB configuration file.